# Magento 2.2.2 Customer register

Tags: magento2.2.2, registration

I am updating the schema of customer_entity and add a field referral code and also add a new field on the registration form. Now I want to add this field data to the customer_entity new column. how can I do

Comment: Why do you add field in customer_entity ?!! You can create customer Attribute for that.

Answer (score 2):

You should create a new custom customer attribute programmatically and not as a field in customer_entity table, it is not a right way to add static columns in customer_entity table unless no other way is available.

I used below code to add Mobile Number.

Create file at below path:

> Vendor/Module/Setup/InstallData.php

```
<?php
  /**
   * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
   * See COPYING.txt for license details.
   */
  namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

  use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
  use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
  use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
  use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
  use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
  use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
  use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

  /**
   * Install data
   * @codeCoverageIgnore
   */
  class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
  {

      /**
       * CustomerSetupFactory
       * @var CustomerSetupFactory
       */
      protected $customerSetupFactory;

      /**
       * $attributeSetFactory
       * @var AttributeSetFactory
       */
      private $attributeSetFactory;

      /**
       * initiate object
       * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
       * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
       */
      public function __construct(
          CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
          AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
      )
      {
          $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
          $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
      }

      /**
       * Install data method
       * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
       * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
       */
      public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
      {

          /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
          $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

          $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
          $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

          /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
          $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
          $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);
          /**
           * customer registration form default field mobile number
           */
          $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'mobile_number', [
              'type' => 'varchar',
              'label' => 'Mobile Number',
              'input' => 'text',
              'required' => true,
              'visible' => true,
              'user_defined' => true,
              'sort_order' => 1000,
              'position' => 1000,
              'system' => 0,
          ]);
          //add attribute to attribute set
          $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'mobile_number')
              ->addData([
                  'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                  'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                  'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_create'],
              ]);

          $attribute->save();


      }
  }
```

After Completion module, Run Below commands.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

If you add code in any existing module, But than after you need to remove module entry from setup table from DB, Than execute above commands.

Comment: I don't want to create backend functionality, Attributes may be operated from backend. I want it to be done from front store register form. If customer register himself a hashcode will be generated and save it to database against user id

Comment: Ok, but still attribute needs to be created. You just don't need to add it in any of the forms for which delete this line from the code - 'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_create']